# XMPP XEP 0333 Implementation in SMACK

Tags: xmpp, openfire, smack, xmppframework, asmack

I am developing a XMPP based chat application. My requirement is that I need to show the read/delivered status like in whatsapp. With some research I came to a understanding that I need to use [XEP-0333](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0333.html) chat markers to achieve this functionality.

In XMPP ios framework we have support for XEP-0333. For android I am using `Smack` library . I don't see any implementation of XEP-0333 in Smack library.Smack has implemented obsolete [XEP-0022](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0022.html), not this one. Could somebody help me on this. How to implement this XEP specification.

Answer (score 0):

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28994590/how-to-implement-message-read-status-like-whatsapp-blue-tick-mark)

It helps you to implement the read status like whatsapp.

For delivery information asmack provides to classes required to add the listener to message then you will get the delivery status of the message.

DeliveryReceiptManager used for receive the delivery resort.